# How to convert a column into an image column through the code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

i have a grid view that is filled through a data-source from the code behind :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // filling the grid view
    MainGrid.DataSource = Update();
    MainGrid.DataBind();

}

protected DataSet Update() 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tim,com,pic FROM ten", conn);
    conn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
```

but i have a file upload that inserts the file-path into the database (and it works fine), but i would like to know how to change the column type to image through the code-behind.

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason for not doing it on the page in front?

Comment: what code is this ? you do not dispose anything....

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat - the table name is different based on a few variables so i need to bind the grid view through the code behind

Comment: @Aristos - its the code i am using the fill the gridview

Comment: @Wahtever you need to dispose some thinks there, or else soon your application can stop working.

Comment: @wahtever - data binding from code behind fine - why can you not define the column types in the page?

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat - you are right , i didn't notice that if just bind it , it will work fine, but i have two image columns now. can i hide one

Comment: @Aristos - im sorry i don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - from the comments - set your column types in the declaration of the grid, and bind your data in the code behind.

If you need variable column types, the simplest route is to include multiple columns, and show and hide them appropriately.

Comment: just had to remove the auto generate columns from the gridview, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose all the disposable objects using the Dispose()....or like

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tim,com,pic FROM ten", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    MainGrid.DataSource = ds;
                }
            } 

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i hate to sound like an idiot, but what do i do it this way instead of the regular way

Comment: @wahtever if you not dispose and close the objects left open, and soon or later you have memory problems. This is needed only on dispsable objects, not on all.

Comment: you are right i just forgot to close the connection , thank you for pointing it out